# Could not find gem 'nested-scaffold x86_64-linux' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

While using rails in WSL
I added the below two lines in the gem file:
`gem 'devise'`
`gem 'nested-scaffold'`

saved the gem file of my recently created rails app and ran `bundle` and then got this error as mentioned `Could not find gem 'nested-scaffold x86_64-linux' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

I tried adding the following but still gives the same error on
`gem 'devise'`
`gem 'nested-scaffold'`
`gem 'nested-scaffold x86_64-linux'`

also tried
`gem 'nested-scaffold_x86_64-linux'`
but still stuck at the above error on running `bundle` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through this website and tried mentioned gemfile text at https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_scaffold/versions/1.1.0
Now, I used
`gem 'nested_scaffold', '~> 1.1'` instead of `gem 'nested_scaffold'` in the Gemfile rest remained the same with `gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3", ">= 7.0.3.1"` in gemfile & saved the gemfile and then ran `bundle` command,

**It worked!**
as it says `Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 80 gems now installed. Use bundle info [gemname] to see where a bundled gem is installed.`
and I also checked the rails gem version and it responded with rails (7.0.3.1)

```
 bundle info rails
  * rails (7.0.3.1)
        Summary: Full-stack web application framework.
        Homepage: https://rubyonrails.org
        Documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3.1/
        Source Code: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v7.0.3.1
        Changelog: https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v7.0.3.1
        Bug Tracker: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues
        Mailing List: https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/c/rubyonrails-talk
        Path: /home/vibhor/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rails-7.0.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the gem you are looking for is

```
gem 'nested_scaffold'
```

it's old though and only works with rails 4.2 and 5.

Comment: oh okay, thank you for the help
Yes, I am using higher version that is `Rails 7.0.3.1`

Comment: recently, I installed `rails v 5.0` and `rails v 4.2.0` using the below commands:
`gem install rails -v 5.0.0` and 
`gem install rails -v 4.2.0`

and replaced the following text
`gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3", ">= 7.0.3.1"`
from
`gem "rails", "~> 4.2.0", ">= 4.2.0"`
now it surpassed that error but came up with other gems version compatibility issues.